# Not able to commit using Git Source Control Provider for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github

I am very new to the GIT world and most of the concept is alien to me. I followed instructions here http://gitscc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Documentation and installed "Git Source Control Provider" with vs 2010. Git Extension and TortoiseGit has also been installed as I saw it in the doc.

I followed other instructions and tried to create repo and perform some commit. I even tried to push as I read somewhere that commit is a local action. But none of this is getting reflected on server i.e. my GitHub account, in-fact it could not even create repo and I had to do it manually at my GitHub account. I think following two things could be a problem.

- I remember the Git Source Control Provider installation did not ask
  for my GitHub credential nor do I see any place where I can specify
  it. I am not sure, could this be a problem? If yes, where to specify
  the credential?
- I tried to push, using HTTP url to my repo but that was taking some
  very huge amount of time (just 1.5 MB). So I thought maybe it will
  not work and cancelled the process.

It is quite possible problem could be something other than the two points I have mentioned above. In any case, can someone help with some insight into the problem? Would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using Git from the command line and forget about the VisualStudio integration. I've been working this way since 2008. VisualStudio integration is over-rated.

The command line will give you

- searchable history of commands that you issued before (even between sessions)
- tab complete for branch names, file names, etc
- scriptability
- output piping so you can combine commands by the output of the predecessor

When you use visual studio integration tools or other gui tools, you lose all these great advantages that git provides.

[MSysGit](http://msysgit.github.com/) is very easy to get started with. Just make sure when you're installing it to set line endings to not be changes when storing files and when retrieving them (unless you are doing work with others on other operating systems). If you missed out on that, you can change them after with

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Also tell git that you're on windows which has it's own line endings. You don't want them to be highlighted as problematic in certain output:

```
git config --system core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

For your credentials issues, set up a project using the instructions [here](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/). The ssh keys setup is key and should work for you if you do what it says.

When following the instructions for installing msysgit, remember to change the line endings option to be the bottom choice.

you can ping me on gtalk if you have issues. (same as my id)

Comment: +1 for "VisualStudio integration is over-rated" -1 for not suggesting another GUI. I think learning the basics on the command line is mandatory, but for daily usage I strongly recommend a GUI. The diff and history on the command line is not sufficient for me. The GitHub app for example is nice, but limited. Alternatives are git gui or TortoiseGit, but they look ugly. A good looking, powerful and platform agnostic solution would be TortoiseHG with hg-git, but of course this implies a drawback, too. Conclusion: No optimal GUI for Git on Windows, but better than command line usage.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Adam. Actually I have to get things up and running ASAP. Yes I agree the command line knowledge is important so as to have total control. I will go through that too but not now.

Comment: @ms4py MSysGit gives you git-gui and gitk if you want gui - show me any gui that gives you more functionality than those 2 combined. They are 2 separate programs for a good reason. "Better than command line usage" is very subjective. Command line is much faster and has lots of advantages over GUI.

Comment: @Packer do try the built in git-gui and gitk. They have more functionality than any other gui tools for git.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [GitHub documentation](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) for the first steps if you are a git beginner. The documentation for the plugin is not really helpful if you are new to git. Or check out [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) as an alternative.

You have to "link" your local repository with the one at GitHub by adding it as "remote" with `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo.git`. How should the local git know that you want to push to GitHub? GitHub is not directly related to git, it is only a hoster for git repositories.

**Edit**: You always have to create a repository at GitHub. The common workflow is:

1. Create a repo at GH
2. Clone it local
3. Make changes locally
4. Commit and push them

In this scenario you don't have to add the "origin" because it is automatically added while cloning it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right I have to link my local repo with that on server. I tried GitHub for Windows but it cannot be integrated with VS so I have to leave it. I will try this and would post about the exact problem.

Comment: @Packer you can use GitHub for Windows and the VS integrated solution side by side. Clone your repo with GitHub and then work with it using the VS plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post amazingly helpful, http://codeasp.net/blogs/vivek_iit/microsoft-net/1881/how-to-user-github-with-visual-studio.

It explains the whole process clearly. Apart the local repo setting I also had problem with SSH key. This post help me get over with all problems. Now everything is smooth.

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.